# Not able to access Flask API outside Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flask, minikube

Hi All I'm new to Kubernetes was deploying a Flask app but cannot access API outside the minikube cluster below are the logs:

Tried all the troubleshooting I could do but no luck
below are details and logs :

API Detail:

```
call: curl http://10.101.180.25:81/api/v1.0/result
expected output: {"result":[]}
```

I'm Able to access from the container itself.

```
user2@abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999-dcgxz:/app$ curl http://10.101.180.25:81/api/v1.0/result
{"result":[]}

user2@abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999-dcgxz:/app$
```

**Additional details:**

Minikube profile:

```
user@machine1:~/project/pro-oso-abc$ minikube profile list
|----------------|-----------|------------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|--------|
|    Profile     | VM Driver |  Runtime   |      IP      | Port | Version | Status  | Nodes | Active |
|----------------|-----------|------------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|--------|
| minikube       | docker    | containerd | 192.168.49.2 | 6443 | v1.26.3 | Stopped |     1 | *      |
| poc-abc-deploy | docker    | containerd | 192.168.58.2 | 8443 | v1.26.3 | Running |     1 |        |
|----------------|-----------|------------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|--------|
```

These are the details of
PODS:

````
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$ kubectl get pods -n abc-poc-ns
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999-dcgxz   1/1     Running   1 (27m ago)   54m
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$```
````

These are the details of
Pod Description:

```
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$ kubectl describe pod abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999-dcgxz -n abc-poc-ns
Name:             abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999-dcgxz
Namespace:        abc-poc-ns
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             poc-abc-deploy/192.168.58.2
Start Time:       Mon, 26 Jun 2023 02:05:30 +0530
Labels:           app=abc-poc
                  pod-template-hash=655c5c5999
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999
Containers:
  abc-poc-container:
    Container ID:   containerd://29aa1cc2e719087443f2e9f65187c9e6b0265eb1cffc5c34d9416f8d6bc149cc
    Image:          user11/abc_poc_repo:v1.1
    Image ID:       sha256:ebc3cd704a425aac030c681959db1e2a65d4412114f0dcd019616070bbee3023
    Port:           5000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 26 Jun 2023 02:32:59 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Unknown
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Mon, 26 Jun 2023 02:05:30 +0530
      Finished:     Mon, 26 Jun 2023 02:32:31 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cht87 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-cht87:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age   From               Message
  ----    ------          ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled       55m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned abc-poc-ns/abc-poc-deployment-655c5c5999-dcgxz to poc-abc-deploy
  Normal  Pulled          55m   kubelet            Container image "user11/abc_poc_repo:v1.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created         55m   kubelet            Created container abc-poc-container
  Normal  Started         55m   kubelet            Started container abc-poc-container
  Normal  SandboxChanged  28m   kubelet            Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  Pulled          28m   kubelet            Container image "user11/abc_poc_repo:v1.1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created         28m   kubelet            Created container abc-poc-container
  Normal  Started         28m   kubelet            Started container abc-poc-container
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$
```

These are the details of
Service:

```
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$ kubectl get svc -n abc-poc-ns
NAME              TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
abc-poc-service   NodePort   10.101.180.25   <none>        81:30701/TCP   85m
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$
```

Service description:

```
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$ kubectl describe svc abc-poc-service -n abc-poc-ns
Name:                     abc-poc-service
Namespace:                abc-poc-ns
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=abc-poc
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.101.180.25
IPs:                      10.101.180.25
Port:                     <unset>  81/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30701/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.3:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
user@machine1:~/practise/deployments/poc_abc_deploy$
```

Can anyone help me Thanks for your time!!

Update:
Also tried by deploying separate [pd and accessing from it
it is working
only outside of minikube cluster I'm not able to access

Comment: You seem to have included a lot of diagnostics, but none of the actual source needed to demonstrate the issue.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What URL are you actually trying to connect to, and how did you get it?  Does the same container work in a non-Kubernetes Docker environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze,   Have updated the details, Yup same container works using only docker,API is accessible from host machine, Have kept the logs and termed as additional info so someone might need to troubleshoot